# Is there any workaround for simpleConsumer module to read only the new messages?

Tags: apache-kafka

As mentioned for simple consumer here

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example

> Also note that we are explicitly checking that the offset being read
>   is not less than the offset that we requested. This is needed since if
>   Kafka is compressing the messages, the fetch request will return an
>   entire compressed block even if the requested offset isn't the
>   beginning of the compressed block. Thus a message we saw previously
>   may be returned again.

Finally, we keep track of the # of messages read. If we didn't read anything on the last request we go to sleep for a second so we aren't hammering Kafka when there is no data.

As in my program it reads one of the old messages first, goes to sleep as it is old, and then reads the new records.

Any work around so that SimpleConsumer reads only new messages?

Answer (score 0):

From the same page

```
    public static long getLastOffset(SimpleConsumer consumer, String topic, int partition,
                                 long whichTime, String clientName) {
    TopicAndPartition topicAndPartition = new TopicAndPartition(topic, partition);
    Map<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo> requestInfo = new HashMap<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo>();
    requestInfo.put(topicAndPartition, new PartitionOffsetRequestInfo(whichTime, 1));
    kafka.javaapi.OffsetRequest request = new kafka.javaapi.OffsetRequest(requestInfo, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.CurrentVersion(),clientName);
    OffsetResponse response = consumer.getOffsetsBefore(request);

    if (response.hasError()) {
        System.out.println("Error fetching data Offset Data the Broker. Reason: " + response.errorCode(topic, partition) );
        return 0;
    }
    long[] offsets = response.offsets(topic, partition);
    return offsets[0];
}
```

It says for finding offset to read

> Kafka includes two constants to help, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime() finds the beginning of the data in the logs and starts streaming from there, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime() will only stream new messages. Don’t assume that offset 0 is the beginning offset, since messages age out of the log over time.

Comment: the answer is a bit irrelevant, since the situation OP describes has nothing to do with 0 as starting offset -- it's quirks of compressed messages.